# UICollctionView didSelectItemAt problems

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to change an UIImage in the collectionviewcell with the help of on didSelectItemAt. It is working when I select cell on the beginning but when I scroll down and scroll back up the images are back to what they were and changed images shift to different cells.

[First cell selected Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P2gX.png)

[Scrolled down then came up Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlFad.png)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! RateCardCollectionViewCell
        let tempString = "\(NSLocalizedString("base_url", comment: ""))\(itemImageLink[indexPath.row])"
        let urlnew:String = tempString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
        let url = URL(string: urlnew)
        cell.rateCardImage.kf.setImage(with: url,placeholder: UIImage(named: "Junkart_Bin.png"))
        cell.label.text = itemName[indexPath.row]
        cell.itemRate.text = itemRate[indexPath.row]
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        cell.card.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.card.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.card.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
        cell.card.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        cell.card.layer.shadowOpacity = 1   //0.8
        return cell
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! RateCardCollectionViewCell
        if self.selectedRate == nil {
            cell.changeImagetoSelected()
            self.selectedRate = [Int]()
            self.selectedRate.append(indexPath.row)
        }
        else {

        }
    }
```

**Following is the UICollectionViewCell Class**

```
class RateCardCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rateCardImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var card: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemRate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var selected_rate_image: UIImageView!
    func changeImagetounSelected() {
        selected_rate_image.image = UIImage(named: "unselected_rate")
    }
    func changeImagetoSelected() {
        selected_rate_image.image = UIImage(named: "selected_rate")
    }
}
```

Please Help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `cell` creation index added on the `selectedRate` at the time of cell creation `cellForItemAt`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! RateCardCollectionViewCell
        // Your remaining codes are here.

        if selectedRate.contains(IndexPath.row) {
           cell.changeImageToSelected()
        } else {
           cell.changeImageTounselected()
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened because collection view dequeue his cells. So you need to persist your selection in dataModel and get if cell is selected or no from it. So persist your selectedIndex in your viewController and in your cellForItemAt method call:

```
if(self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row){
    cell.changeImageToSelected()
}
else{
    cell.changeImageTounselected()
}
```

This will persist your selection when scroll